# Comprobar permisos datos móviles en iOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, permisos

quiero comprobar si el usuario ha autorizado o no el acceso a datos móviles  en la aplicación, igual que se comprueba si hay permiso para micrófono, cámara, notificaciones.... 
Pero no encuentro cómo consultarlo.
He visto soluciones comprobando si hay conexión a internet o no, pero no es lo que busco, ya que la intención es saber si ha dado permiso o no, aunque no tenga cobertura o conexión en ese momento.

gracias